# Typescript error Type 'string | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript,react.
I want to adapt each px size when one of xs, sm, md, lg is passed in props.
I used Record as follows, but I get a typescript error.

tsError

```
Type 'string | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.ts(2344)
```

```
export type IconProps = {
  fontSize?: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
  padding?: number;
  margin?: number;
};

export const FONTSIZE: Record<IconProps['fontSize'], string> = {
  xs: '14px',
  sm: '16px',
  md: '18px',
  lg: '24px',
};
```

①

```
import { Icon } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React from 'react';
import { IconProps, FONTSIZE } from '../theme/iconProps';


export const ArrowRightIcon: React.FunctionComponent<IconProps> = ({
  fontSize,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Icon fontSize={FONTSIZE[fontSize]} {...props}>
      <path d="" /> // Abbreviation
    </Icon>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fontSize?: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
```

One of the possible values here is `undefined`, due to the `?` which makes it optional. But `undefined` can't be the key of an object, so when you try to make a record with these as the keys, typescript complains.

You can exclude `undefined` by using [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype):

```
export const FONTSIZE: Record<NonNullable<IconProps['fontSize']>, string> = {
  xs: '14px',
  sm: '16px',
  md: '18px',
  lg: '24px',
};
```

Or if you prefer, [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) is another option:

```
export const FONTSIZE: Record<Exclude<IconProps['fontSize'], undefined>, string> = {
  xs: '14px',
  sm: '16px',
  md: '18px',
  lg: '24px',
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSBjCA7AClCMAZzgF44BvAKDjgDMcYBlASwC9gB%20ALjgHIQRPnAA%20-IgFthYvhIAm0-gBsA5nwDcNOGACGcuS2wqecbAFcJAI2BRNtCTqgrDJ81ZuaAvpqqhIsOCxsIngAMQB5ADkAFSY0AC0AUV4AJWAsKDkAHkicSLMlJR1LJWAszBx8QiIAbT4GbGZ2YD4AXQA%20ABo4EKhDFXaySi1BXj4ARgAWMBA%20Tq1JMfGANhm5rXklgA41%20dpVMYAmadn57yA)

Answer (score 3):

`IconProps['fontSize']` is optional. It means the value could be `undefined`. However, `undefined` could not be a key of the `object`. You can use `Required` to exclude the `undefined` situation of `IconProps`.

```
export const FONTSIZE: Record<Required<IconProps>['fontSize'], string> = {
  xs: '14px',
  sm: '16px',
  md: '18px',
  lg: '24px',
};
```